# how to make a button appear disappear on click of another button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am facing problem with toggling of appearance of button in my react project.

I am working on a mini react project. I want my show button to toggle appearance of another button valued "submit" using react/JSX and not using CSS.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var show;
class FormComp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show : Boolean()
    }
    this.handleshow = this.handleshow.bind(this);
  }

  handleshow() {
    this.setState ((prevState) => {
      return {
        show : !prevState.show
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    <form onSubmit={this.handlesubmit}>
      <input type="submit" value="Show" onClick = {this.handleshow}/>

      { this.state.show ? <button>Submit</button> : null }
    </form> 
    </div>
  );
}}

export default FormComp;
```

Is there any problem with my conditional rendering statement?

Comment: The code in your `render()` function should throw an error... there's a `</div>` with no opening tag.

Comment: that's a typo. It's there in my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional rendering is good, the problem comes when you are updating your `show` state , so in your `handleShow` function make a little change

```
handleshow() {
this.setState ((prevState) => {
  return {
  show : !prevState.show
}});}
```

Plus, change the type submit of show button to type button.
That will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for helping . I did as you mentioned and made one more change in my "this.state"  by changing value of  show to "show: Boolean()" as if i set show to true in "this.state", code will not work. Plus one more thing,after changes, on clicking show button, submit button appears for a moment and then disappears till i click show button again. How can I make it that it toggle appearance on every click i.e appears on click, disappears on click and so on.

Comment: You should use your this.state as simple as possible , so you should use a show : true, remember if you use Boolean(), so your as passing as argument an empty value so Boolean constructor will consider it as a falsy value so , your initial state will be false , so it’s better to set a literal value as true or false directly without using the Boolean constructor

Comment: Legit. It's appearing for a moment only. But what about that?

Comment: Ok your problem is that your show button has a type submit , so that button should be a type=‘button’, so when you clickling into your show button you are making a submit event and the form is sending data and refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

this might help you. read the comment in the code to understand more. and on the other hand you don't need to declare variable and it's data type to use it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FormComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show : false
    }
    this.handleshow = this.handleshow.bind(this);
  }

  handleshow() {
    // toggle your show state
    // for example if your show state is false than it will be true and if true than it will be false
    //exclamation mark(!) will work as not operator
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handlesubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Show" onClick = {this.handleshow}/>
        // when your show state is true submit button will show up otherwise it will not shown up
        { this.state.show ? <button>Submit</button> : null }
       </form> 
    </div>
    )
  );
}}

export default FormComp;
```